# Rotate collectionView in circle following user direction

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, rotation, uipangesturerecognizer

I am trying create collectionView with circuler layout and I want the collectionView to rotate in circle as the user swipe his finger on screen round in whatever direction. I found the circle layout for collectionView here is what I have done so far

[image]

to rotate this collectionView I have wrote this code

add gesture to collectionView

```
panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.gestureReader(_:)))
    panGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    self.collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
```

here is the gestureReader and animation methods

```
@objc private func gestureReader(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    var startLocation = CGPoint.zero
    var endLocation = CGPoint.zero
    let currentLocation = gesture.location(in: self.collectionView)

    if gesture.state == .began {
        startLocation = currentLocation
    }

    if gesture.state == .ended {
        endLocation = currentLocation
        self.startRotatingView(start: startLocation, end: endLocation)
    }
}

private func startRotatingView(start:CGPoint, end: CGPoint) {
    let dx = end.x - start.x
    let dy = end.y - start.y

    let distance = abs(sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy))
    print(distance)


    if start.x > end.x {
        if start.y > end.y {
            //positive value of pi
            self.circleAnimation(-distance)
        }else {
            //negitive value of pi
            self.circleAnimation(distance)
        }
    }else {
        if start.y > end.y {
            //positive value of pi
            self.circleAnimation(-distance)
        }else {
            //negitive value of pi
            self.circleAnimation(distance)
        }
    }
}

private func circleAnimation(_ angle:CGFloat) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7, delay: 0,  options: .curveLinear, animations: {
        self.collectionView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        self.collectionView.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle: angle)
    }) { (true) in
        //
    }
}
```

First the animation is not working properly and second when collectionView gets rotated this is what I get

[image]

Question1 : What else do I need to add to make this animation smooth and follow user's finger?
Question2 : I want the collectionViewcells to stay as before animation, how can I achieve this, please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use a collection circular layout and dynamic items behavior will solve your problems very easily

Comment: can you please explain with some code or share any demo source please

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCustomLayouts/CreatingCustomLayouts.html

Answer (score 3):

I show you an example here. The decor View S1View is a subclass of UICollectionViewCell with the identifier "background".

The code is not hard to understand but tedious to put together. How to control animator is another story.

```
        class TestCollectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {

            lazy var dataSource : UICollectionViewDataSource? = {
                self.collectionView?.dataSource
            }()

            var layouts : [IndexPath: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes?] = [:]

            var itemNumber : Int  {
                return   dataSource!.collectionView(collectionView!, numberOfItemsInSection: 0)
            }

            override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]?{
                var itemArray = (0..<itemNumber).map{ self.layoutAttributesForItem(at: IndexPath.init(row: $0, section: 0))!}
                itemArray.append(self.layoutAttributesForDecorationView(ofKind:"background"
                    , at: IndexPath.init(row: 0, section: 0)))
                return itemArray
            }

            override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize { get{
                return  self.collectionView?.frame.size ?? CGSize.zero
                }
            }

            lazy var  dynamicAnimator = {UIDynamicAnimator(collectionViewLayout: self)}()

            private func updateCurrentLayoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath, current: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes?) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes?{
                return current
            }

            private func initLayoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes?{
                let layoutAttributes =   UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)
                let center = (collectionView?.center)!
                let angle = (CGFloat(indexPath.row)  /  CGFloat(itemNumber) * CGFloat.pi * 2)
                layoutAttributes.center = CGPoint.init(x:  center.x + cos(angle) * CGFloat(radius)   , y: center.y + sin(angle) * CGFloat(radius) )
                layoutAttributes.bounds  = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100 )

                if let decorator = self.decorator {
                    let itemBehavior =
                        UIAttachmentBehavior.pinAttachment(with: layoutAttributes, attachedTo: decorator, attachmentAnchor: layoutAttributes.center)
                    dynamicAnimator.addBehavior(itemBehavior)
                    layouts[indexPath] = layoutAttributes
                }
                return layoutAttributes
            }

            override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes?{
                guard let currentLayout = layouts[indexPath] else {
                    return initLayoutAttributesForItem(at:indexPath)}
                return currentLayout
            }


            private let radius = 200

            private var decorator: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes?

            override func layoutAttributesForDecorationView(ofKind elementKind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes{
                guard let decorator = self.decorator else {
                    let layoutAttributes =   UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes.init(forDecorationViewOfKind: elementKind, with: indexPath)
                    layoutAttributes.center = (self.collectionView?.center)!
                    layoutAttributes.bounds = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: radius, height: radius)
                    self.decorator = layoutAttributes
                    return layoutAttributes
                }
                return decorator
            }


            lazy var s: UIDynamicItemBehavior = {
             let decorator = self.decorator!
             let s =   UIDynamicItemBehavior.init(items: [decorator])
             s.angularResistance = 1
             dynamicAnimator.addBehavior(s)
                return s
            }()


            func rotate(_ speed: CGFloat){
                   guard let decorator = self.decorator else {return}
                s.addAngularVelocity(speed, for: decorator)
            }

        }



    class TestCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {


        var startLocation = CGPoint.zero
        var endLocation = CGPoint.zero

        @objc private func gestureReader(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

            let currentLocation = gesture.location(in: self.collectionView)

            if gesture.state == .began {
                startLocation = currentLocation
            }

           else  if gesture.state == .ended {
                endLocation = currentLocation
                self.startRotatingView(start: startLocation, end: endLocation)
            }
        }

        private func startRotatingView(start:CGPoint, end: CGPoint) {
            let dx = end.x - start.x
            let dy = end.y - start.y

            let distance = abs(sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy))




            if start.x < end.x {
                if start.y > end.y {
                    //positive value of pi
                    self.circleAnimation(-distance)
                }else {
                    //negitive value of pi
                    self.circleAnimation(distance)
                }
            }else {
                if start.y > end.y {
                    //positive value of pi
                    self.circleAnimation(-distance)
                }else {
                    //negitive value of pi
                    self.circleAnimation(distance)
                }
            }
        }

        private func circleAnimation(_ angle:CGFloat) {

            (collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? TestCollectionViewLayout).map{
                $0.rotate(angle / 100)
            }
  //                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7, delay: 0,  options: .curveLinear, animations: {
  //                    self.collectionView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
  //                    self.collectionView.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle: angle)
  //                }) { (true) in
  //                    //
 //                }
        }



        override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        //                Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: false) { (Timer) in
       //                    self.rotate()
  //                }
        }

        override func viewDidLoad() {


            super.viewDidLoad()
            collectionView.collectionViewLayout = TestCollectionViewLayout()
            collectionView.collectionViewLayout.register(UINib.init(nibName: "S1View", bundle: nil) , forDecorationViewOfKind: "background")

         let   panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.gestureReader(_:)))
            panGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
            self.collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)

        }

        var data: [Int] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
        override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }

        override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return data.count
        }

        override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)

            return cell
      }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Looks good, I will accept the answer after trying, thank you so much brother

Comment: Can you help me with question1 which is rotation following finger

Comment: Too complicated.

Comment: I link your rotation function with the animation. There are errors in startlocaition.

Comment: what error  can you explain maybe we can solve it together

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this tutorial will help: https://www.raywenderlich.com/1702-uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-a-spinning-wheel

Your first problem is that you are rotating the whole collection view. Think of it like you are putting those circles on a piece of paper and then rotating that piece of paper. You don't want to rotate the whole collection view. You might not want to rotate the circles around a point because then the rotation affects the image and text in the circle. You just want to change the circle's position in a circular movement.

If the UICollectionView isn't working, you could ditch it and use regular UIViews and position them in a circular pattern (These functions should help: https://gist.github.com/akhilcb/8d03f1f88f87e996aec24748bdf0ce78). Once you have the views laid out in a circle then you just need to update the angle for each view as the user drags their finger. Store the previous angle on the view and add to it whatever you want when the user drags their finger. Little bit of trial and error and it shouldn't be too bad.

**Update**

The main reason to use collection views is if you have a lot of items and you need to reuse views like a list. If you don't need to reuse views then using a UICollectionView can be pain to understand, customize and change things. Here is a simple example of using regular views that rotate around a circle using a UIPanGestureRecognizer input.

**Example**:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  var rotatingViews = [RotatingView]()
  let numberOfViews = 8
  var circle = Circle(center: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 200), radius: 100)
  var prevLocation = CGPoint.zero

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for i in 0...numberOfViews {
      let angleBetweenViews = (2 * Double.pi) / Double(numberOfViews)
      let viewOnCircle = RotatingView(circle: circle, angle: CGFloat(Double(i) * angleBetweenViews))
      rotatingViews.append(viewOnCircle)
      view.addSubview(viewOnCircle)
    }

    let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didPan(panGesture:)))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
  }

  @objc func didPan(panGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer){
    switch panGesture.state {
    case .began:
      prevLocation = panGesture.location(in: view)
    case .changed, .ended:
      let nextLocation = panGesture.location(in: view)
      let angle = circle.angleBetween(firstPoint: prevLocation, secondPoint: nextLocation)

      rotatingViews.forEach({ $0.updatePosition(angle: angle)})
      prevLocation = nextLocation
    default: break
    }
  }
}


struct Circle {
  let center: CGPoint
  let radius: CGFloat

  func pointOnCircle(angle: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
    let x = center.x + radius * cos(angle)
    let y = center.y + radius * sin(angle)

    return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
  }

  func angleBetween(firstPoint: CGPoint, secondPoint: CGPoint) -> CGFloat {
    let firstAngle = atan2(firstPoint.y - center.y, firstPoint.x - center.x)
    let secondAnlge = atan2(secondPoint.y - center.y, secondPoint.x - center.x)
    let angleDiff = (firstAngle - secondAnlge) * -1

    return angleDiff
  }
}


class RotatingView: UIView {
  var currentAngle: CGFloat
  let circle: Circle

  init(circle: Circle, angle: CGFloat) {
    self.currentAngle = angle
    self.circle = circle
    super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 60))
    center = circle.pointOnCircle(angle: currentAngle)
    backgroundColor = .blue
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  func updatePosition(angle: CGFloat) {
    currentAngle += angle
    center = circle.pointOnCircle(angle: currentAngle)
  }
}
```

Circle is a struct that just holds the center of all the views, how far apart you want them (radius), and helper functions for calculating the angles found in the GitHub link above.

RotatingViews are the views that rotate around the middle.

Comment: can you explain it with some code. I already saw these codes but not sure how to use these in my case as I am not very good a modifying libraries and I am a bit new to animations and stuff like that. thank you

Comment: I added an example.